# CSS cross browser compatibility with Select element

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a form `select` element with the following CSS:

```
    border:solid 0 #000;
    background: transparent url("../images/input_fld.png") no-repeat;
    height:42px;
    width:275px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:0px;
    font-family: monospace;
```

This generates the select box like this:

**Webkit**

[image: webkit]

**Moz**

[image: moz]

**IE**

[image: ie]

How can I fix this?

I tried adding this for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
form select {padding-bottom:10px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

And while this does fix the issue of the text being bottom aligned, it introduces the issue of also pushing the down arrow up by 10px.

Comment: Styling form elements the same cross browser and cross os is extremely difficult. I think if you _must_ style them at all you're better off using a JS replacement (but try to make sure it's accessible). Here's a good article about the stying of form controls: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/

Comment: You might want to take a look at Formalize.me (http://formalize.me/). Perhaps you can find some ideas from it.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not averse to using a JQuery plugin, you can trying using http://www.verot.net/jquery_select_skin.htm. You'll have to style it a little bit but that's fairly simple.

The plugin doesn't have support for IE6, but I believe that's always for the best :) Also, try adding a line-height to your CSS, equal to the height of the select box, in this case, 42px.

Hope this helps.